# ¿Cómo navegar hacia una DetailView haciendo click en un item de una LazyColumn en JetPack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

estoy intentando crear una app con JetPack Compose (es la primera vez que lo hago) y estoy teniendo algún problema con la navegación. La aplicación tiene un bottomBar con 3 items que navega hacia la pantalla seleccionada.

Hasta aquí bien, el problema es cuando intento acceder al uno de los items de una LazyColumn que se encuentra en una de las pantallas. Me gustaría navegar hacia otra pantalla (Profile) donde se muestren los datos del item seleccionado pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo. Da igual como intente hacerlo, siempre me sale esto "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function".

¿Alguien podría ayudarme explicándome como hacerlo mediante algún ejemplo? Lo que quiero es aprender cómo y por qué, no copiar sin más.

Gracias

Dejo el código por aquí.

### **Solución**

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

            SideEffect {
                systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = PrimaryDark)
            }
            AppTheme() {


                MainScreen()

            }

        }
    }

    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    @Composable
    fun MainScreen() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val navigationItems = listOf(Obras, Talleres, Ajustes)
        Scaffold(bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(
                navController = navController,
                items = navigationItems
            )
        }) {

            NavigationHost(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationHost.kt**

```kotlin
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun NavigationHost(navController: NavHostController) {


    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Obras.route) {
        composable(Obras.route) {
            Pantalla1(navigateToProfile = { authorId ->
                navController.navigate("${Profile.route}/$authorId")
            })

        }
        composable(Talleres.route) {
            Pantalla2()
        }

        composable(Ajustes.route) {
            Pantalla3()
        }

        composable(
            Profile.route + "/{authorId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("authorId") { type = NavType.StringType })
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val authorId = backStackEntry.arguments!!.getString("authorId")!!
            Profile(authorId)
        }

    }
}
```

**Pantalla1.kt**

```kotlin
typealias AuthorId = String

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun Pantalla1(navigateToProfile: (AuthorId) -> Unit) {


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(
                paddingValues = PaddingValues(

                    bottom = 50.dp
                )
            ),
    ) {

        AutoresInfo(navigateToProfile)
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutoresInfo(navigateToProfile: (AuthorId) -> Unit) {
    var autoresList by remember {
        mutableStateOf<List<Autor>?>(null)
    }

    JetFirestore(path = { collection("autores") },
        queryOnCollection = { orderBy("nombre", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) },

        onRealtimeCollectionFetch = { value, exception ->
            autoresList = value.getListOfObjects()
        }) {
        autoresList?.let {
            val grouped = it.groupBy { it.nombre[0] }
            LazyColumn(

                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

            ) {


                grouped.forEach { (initial, autoresForInitial) ->
                    stickyHeader {
                        StickyHeaderAutores(initial = initial.toString())
                    }

                    items(autoresForInitial, key = { autor -> autor.nombre }) { autor ->
                        Surface(modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigateToProfile(autor.nombre) }) {
                            @OptIn(coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi::class)
                            AutorCard(autor)
                        }


                    }
                }


            }
        } ?: Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier

                    .size(50.dp)

            )
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: La pregunta necesita un poco más de explicación. Entiendo que quieres navegar a `Profile` pero no queda claro desde dónde ni con qué argumentos. Tampoco se ve ningún intento de navegación. Incluso si no funciona, debes mostrar el código de lo que has intentado para que podamos indicarte cual fue el error. También deberías mostrar como defines `Profile`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Ya lo he conseguido, actualizo con la solución por si le sirve a alguien.

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu solución pero deberías colocarla como respuesta, no en la pregunta. La sección de respuestas es abajo.

Comment: Vale, perdón, ya está hecho, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

### **Solución**

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

            SideEffect {
                systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = PrimaryDark)
            }
            AppTheme() {


                MainScreen()

            }

        }
    }

    @ExperimentalFoundationApi
    @Composable
    fun MainScreen() {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val navigationItems = listOf(Obras, Talleres, Ajustes)
        Scaffold(bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(
                navController = navController,
                items = navigationItems
            )
        }) {

            NavigationHost(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationHost.kt**

```kotlin
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun NavigationHost(navController: NavHostController) {


    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Obras.route) {
        composable(Obras.route) {
            Pantalla1(navigateToProfile = { authorId ->
                navController.navigate("${Profile.route}/$authorId")
            })

        }
        composable(Talleres.route) {
            Pantalla2()
        }

        composable(Ajustes.route) {
            Pantalla3()
        }

        composable(
            Profile.route + "/{authorId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("authorId") { type = NavType.StringType })
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val authorId = backStackEntry.arguments!!.getString("authorId")!!
            Profile(authorId)
        }

    }
}
```

**Pantalla1.kt**

```kotlin
typealias AuthorId = String

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
fun Pantalla1(navigateToProfile: (AuthorId) -> Unit) {


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(
                paddingValues = PaddingValues(

                    bottom = 50.dp
                )
            ),
    ) {

        AutoresInfo(navigateToProfile)
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutoresInfo(navigateToProfile: (AuthorId) -> Unit) {
    var autoresList by remember {
        mutableStateOf<List<Autor>?>(null)
    }

    JetFirestore(path = { collection("autores") },
        queryOnCollection = { orderBy("nombre", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) },

        onRealtimeCollectionFetch = { value, exception ->
            autoresList = value.getListOfObjects()
        }) {
        autoresList?.let {
            val grouped = it.groupBy { it.nombre[0] }
            LazyColumn(

                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

            ) {


                grouped.forEach { (initial, autoresForInitial) ->
                    stickyHeader {
                        StickyHeaderAutores(initial = initial.toString())
                    }

                    items(autoresForInitial, key = { autor -> autor.nombre }) { autor ->
                        Surface(modifier = Modifier.clickable { navigateToProfile(autor.nombre) }) {
                            @OptIn(coil.annotation.ExperimentalCoilApi::class)
                            AutorCard(autor)
                        }


                    }
                }


            }
        } ?: Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier

                    .size(50.dp)

            )
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).